# How to write a generator to fine-tune transformer based models (Tensorflow)

Tags: keras, tensorflow, bert, transformer

I have been trying to write a generator for DistillBertFast model

```
## Generator
def _generator(text=train_texts, label=Y_oh_train, batch_size=1):
# label = tf.ragged.constant(label)
while True:
    for i in range(0,len(text),batch_size):
        yield dict(tokenizer(text[i:i+batch_size], truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors='tf')), label[i:i+batch_size]

## tf Dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(_generator, output_types=({'input_ids':tf.int32,
                                                                      'attention_mask':tf.int32}, tf.float32))


## model compile

    loss_fn=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
    loss=loss_fn,
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])

## sample data
train_texts = ['This gif kills me Death is literally gushing towards you and you really gon do a whole 3point turn', 'LOVE TEST Raw Real JaDine', 'We would like to wish everyone a very Happy New Year and all the best in 2018']

Y_oh_train=array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
    0.]])
```

But when I try to fit the model it gives error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-195-05df82e86e2e> in <module>()
      4     loss=loss_fn,
      5     metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy])
----> 6 model.fit(t)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 764             *args, **kwds))
    765 
    766     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3287             arg_names=arg_names,
   3288             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3289             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3290         self._function_attributes,
   3291         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_tf_distilbert.py:800 call  *
        distilbert_output = self.distilbert(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_tf_distilbert.py:415 call  *
        embedding_output = self.embeddings(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_tf_distilbert.py:122 call  *
        final_embeddings = self.LayerNorm(inputs=final_embeddings)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1030 __call__  **
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/normalization.py:1218 call
        ndims = len(input_shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:855 __len__
        raise ValueError("Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.")

ValueError: Cannot take the length of shape with unknown rank.
```

I have been trying to find a work around, I can't put in a fixed tensor shape in generator because I can't control the shape of output from generator, it'd be based on the max length on each call, I can't load all the data at once, since the data is too huge to be loaded in memory

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a generator but had to mention the output shape

```
def padded_tokenizer(text, max_len=80):
    result = dict(tokenizer(text, truncation=True, padding=True, return_tensors='tf', pad_to_multiple_of=2))
    for key in result.keys():
        result[key] = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(result[key], padding="post", maxlen=max_len)
    return result

def _generator(arg=0, batch_size=1):
    if arg==0:
        text=train_texts
        label=Y_oh_train
    if arg==1:
        text=val_texts
        label=Y_oh_val
    else:
        text=test_texts
        label=Y_oh_test
    # batch_size=1
    # label = tf.ragged.constant(label)
    while True:
        for i in range(0,len(text),batch_size):
            yield padded_tokenizer(text[i:i+batch_size]), label[i:i+batch_size]

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(_generator, output_signature=({'input_ids':tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,80), dtype=tf.int32),
                                                                          'attention_mask':tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,80), dtype=tf.int32)},
                                                                          tf.TensorSpec(shape=(None,49), dtype=tf.int32)), 
                                               args=([0,16])
                                               )
```

It seems the signature has to be mentioned if output is generated from a generator, but the speed is too slow, compared to loading everything in memory(for obv reasons)

Still would appreciate a faster solution